# Using Resources in Exceptions

Tags: android

I have an app that uses custom Exceptions, such as this:

```
public class SomeException extends Exception{
    private int         iCode;
    private String      iMessage;

    public SomeException(){
        iCode = 201;
        iMessage = **//Get the localized string R.string.error_201??**
    }


    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return iMessage;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCode() {
        return iCode;
    }

}
```

Obviously, I want lo localize the error message. I have possible solutions but non of them satisfy me.

1) Pass "Context" to the constructor, and do ctx.getString(R.string.error_201)
    --> Fail, as this Exceptions are sometimes thrown from MODEL classes, so they don't have a Context

2) Pass "Context" when retriveing the message in getMessage() function,
    --> Fail, It's necesary to override the super method, to work as all other Exceptions.

Solution I have now: All activities in my app have this onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(...){
    Utils.RESOURCES = getResources();
    ...
}
```

Very dirty code... I don't like the solution. My question is then,: is there a way to access the resources without the Context? And most important, How would an application such as mine solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
  private int iCode;

  public MyException(int code) {
    this.iCode = code;
  }

  @Override
  public String getMessage() {
    return "MyException code " + String.valueOf(iCode);
  }

  public String getLocalizedMessage(Context ctx) {
    String message;
    if (iCode == 201)
      message = ctx.getString(R.string.error_201);
    else if (iCode == 202)
      message = ctx.getString(R.string.error_202);
    // ...

  }
}
```

Even if there was way to access context in different way, you should not do it. If you need to emit exceptions where you cannot pass Context, you should be able to access context before you display such error. I cannot see reason why you should create localized error messages from constructor. You can log to logcat not localized versions if you need. And where you want to display something in UI, you should have context at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can access only system wide resources without Context.

You need a Context, so I would suggest You to get it as soon as possible, and make it available through a static method or variable. You do the same thing in every Activity, but there is a cleaner method. You should make a custom Application, and override its onCreate() to make the resources public:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Resources myResources;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        myResources = getBaseContext().getResources();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static Resources getMyResources(){
        return myResources;
    }
}
```

The other thing you have to do is to set the Application in your manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name="{your_package}.App"
        ...
```

Now you can access the resources in all of your Activity without any preparation. Your custom Exception class could also use the externalized resources.